# Dilogarithm, tetrahedrons, and hyperbolic space

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, special-functions, polyhedra, polylogarithms

The Bloch-Wigner function $D(z)$ gives the volume of an ideal tetrahedron in the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^3$. Here $z$ is the cross-ratio $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ parametrizing the tetrahedron in $\mathbb{C}P^1$.
Put $\tilde D(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4) = D(z)$.

The five-term relation for the dilogarithm could be interpreted as the fact that the signed sum of some volumes of tetrahedra vanishes:

$$\sum^4_{i=0} (-1)^i \tilde D(z_0, ...., \hat z_i, ... z_4) = 0$$

Here the $z_i$ are 5 points in $\mathbb{C}P^1$, and the notation $\hat z_i$ means  that we 
don't take the vertex $z_i$ in account. 
The above equation  looks like some function of a boundary of some 5-simplex.

But what is this 5-simplex (which, I think, corresponds to a 4-volume), and in what space this simplex exists (hyperbolic space ?) ?

Reference (Zagier) : http://maths.dur.ac.uk/~dma0hg/dilog.pdf   (Pages 10 - 11)

Comment: I guess you mean $z_i \in \mathbb{H}^3$. There is no need to create a $4$-dimensional space. Think about the simpler situation of a quadrilateral in the plane. This defines a $4$-simplex, and the alternated sum of areas of triangles is zero.

Comment: The $z_i$ are in $CP1$, the boundary of $H3$. Thanks for your answer

Comment: You're right $z_i \in \partial \mathbb{H}^3$. Of course, the fact about volumes is true regardless whether the $z_i$'s are on the boundary or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The five term relation comes from the fact that the sum of the volumes of tetrahedra $ABCD$ and $ABCE$ equals the sum of the volumes of the three tetrahedra $ABDE, ACDE, BCDE.$ One can think of $ABCDE$ as a degenerate four-dimensional simplex.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this follows from Stokes' theorem. Consider the 4-simplex $\sigma$ with vertices ABCDE. Since the volume form $\omega$ is closed we have $$\int_{\partial\sigma}\omega=\int_{\sigma} d\omega=0.$$
But the integral of the volume form over $\partial\sigma$ is exactly the alternating sum $$\sum_{i=0}^4\left(-1\right)^i vol(\partial_i\sigma)=\sum_{i=0}^4\left(-1\right)^i \tilde{D}\left(z_0,\ldots,\hat{z}_i,\ldots,z_4\right).$$

Comment: I agree, in fact here the non-trivial fact is that the five-term dilogarithm relation is linked to very specific 3-volumes in hyperbolic space (ABCD, ABCE, ABDE, ACDE, BCDE). 

So, yes,  there is a 3-volume form which is closed.